# Protractor webdriver not working with chrome version 54

Tags: webdriver, protractor

Wondered if someone could help. Just started using protractor to automate our tests. These were working fine but now when chrome is launching it closes straight away. I've been told my webdriver needs updating but I can't seem to get it to go past version 2.22. When doing new webdriver-manager update it still goes to the older version. Also been to the website to get the zip file but no matter where I put it I can't get it up update.

This is for a mac machine. Any tips would be appreciated. When I go to localhost:4444/wd/hub', when the web driver has been started and click start session it fails. This has only started since chrome updated to version 54.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to update your webdriver-manager (chromedriver to 2.24), but as i observed, 'webdriver-manager update' command is not updatinng chromedriver to 2.24, so the workaround is just remove the protractor and webdriver-manager from your system and install it again.

To remove webdriver-manager and protractor from global:
just delete folders from 'C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules'

And install it again by using:
'npm install -g webdriver-manager',
'npm install -g protractor'

Comment: Thanks for replying. However doing this has still installed the older version of the webdriver.

Comment: can you plz share how you doing installation?, did you reinstalled protractor as well ?

Comment: There is a known issue with webdriver-manager on osx that prevents it from downloading any chromedriver past 2.22. https://github.com/angular/webdriver-manager/issues/93